# How to use update_{$meta_type}_metadata filter to modify meta value

Tags: filters, post-meta

I'm trying to wrap my head around the `update_{$meta_type}_metadata` filter, in order to modify both post and user metadata before database insertion.

After reading the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/update_(meta_type)_metadata) and the [core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L184), it seems to me the filter must return `null` for the `add_metadata` function to continue. However, this means it is impossible to filter the `$meta_value` since returning a non-null value short-circuits the function.

What am I missing here? And, more generally, what is the point of having the filter at all when it can only return `null`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code snippet in question is:

```
$check = apply_filters( "update_{$meta_type}_metadata", 
    null, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
if ( null !== $check )
    return (bool) $check;
```

This filter only allows you to **prevent** the updating of the metadata for a given type, not to explicitly change the metadata itself.

If you want to use this filter to modify the metadata, you could try for example:

```
add_filter( 'update_post_metadata', 'wpse_163859', 10, 5 );
update_post_meta( $post_id = 123, 'test', 'ABCDEF' );
```

where:

```
function wpse_163859( $check, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value )
{
    // Avoid infinite recursion:
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); 

    // Modify the meta value;
    $meta_value = strtolower( $meta_value ); 

    // Do something else ...

    // Update the modified value.
    update_post_meta( $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); 

    // Return something else than null
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was this infinite recurive problem that I had already encountered as well. Awesome help thanks!