# Grab meta data before post is saved

Tags: posts, hooks, post-meta, actions

I'm trying to grab the metadata for a post before it is saved. I know that I could use the 'post_updated' hook (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/)  to grab the before/after values of the post itself, but I'm not seeing where I can do the same for metadata.

Is this even possible?

Comment: [How to use update_{$meta_type}_metadata filter to modify meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163859/how-to-use-update-meta-type-metadata-filter-to-modify-meta-value). Also, check out the hooks that fire during the [update_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata/) function.

Comment: Didn't even know that existed. Will check it out. Thank you!